# Confusion over extending abstract classes in C++

Tags: c++, abstract-class

In my header file for `Class1` I have:

```
class Class1 : Class2::Callback {

  public:

  //Class2::Callback method
  virtual bool class2Method(int i);

}
```

in `Class1.cxx` I have:

```
bool Class1::class2Method(int i) {
  if (i == 1) return true;
  return false;
}
```

In another place I have:

```
IWantAClass2Callback((Class2::Callback)instanceOfClass1);
```

When I try and compile I get the following error:

```
MyApp.cxx In constructor 'MyApp()':
MyApp.cxx:55:55: error: 'Class2::Callback is an inaccessible base of Class1'
MyApp.cxx:55:55: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Class2::Callback'
Class2.h:16:10: note:    because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Class2::Callback'
Class2.h:19:18: note:    virtual bool Class2::Callback::class2Method(int)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the definition of `Class2::Callback` as defined in `Class2.h` :

```
class Class2
{
public:
  struct Callback {
    virtual bool class2Method(int i) = 0;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have used [private inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c) here. The declaration of `Class1` should look like this:

```
class Class1 : public Class2::Callback { // note the keyword "public" here
public:
    //Class2::Callback method
    virtual bool class2Method(int i);
};
```

Comment: Then you need to show us more code. Specifically, the definition of `Class2::Callback`.

Comment: @TomMedley the error is quite clear: `Class2::CallBack` is an inaccessible base of `Class1` means that at the place of the error the relationship is not, well, accessible, which means that it is not `public` (could be either `private` or `protected`). Go back and check where you added the access specifier... The second error line indicates that you have not overridden the pure virtual function, so you might have other issues (is the definition of `Class2::CallBack` visible while defining `Class1`?? Are those the first compiler errors you get?)

Comment: @TomMedley: Hm, in [this example](http://ideone.com/TGJ04) it works. Can you find a significant difference?

Answer (score 1):

In c++ the default access specifier for classes is private:

```
 class Class1 : public Class2::Callback
```

Should do the trick. That or make it a struct whose default access specifier is public.

Answer (score 1):

There're two problems in your code:

1. As many pointed out, you used private inheritance instead of public
   one.
2. You use slicing when converting to `Class2::Callback`: `(Class2::Callback)instanceOfClass1`. To use polimorphism you need a pointer or a reference. Assuming that you `IWantAClass2Callback` has following signature:

   `void IWantAClass2Callback(Class2::Callback&);`

   (return type doesn't matter), correct call would be:

   `IWantAClass2Callback(instanceOfClass1);`

Answer (score 0):

The Callback must reside in `public:` area of `Class2`, is that the case? I mean:

```
class Class2 {
public:
     class Callback {
         virtual bool class2Method(int) = 0
     };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have

```
IWantAClass2Callback((Class2::Callback)instanceOfClass1);
```

in there? what do you expect it to do? you can cast pointers and references, but no instances.

try changing the signature to

```
void IWantAClass2Callback(Class2::Callback &instance)
```

and calling

```
IWantAClass2Callback((Class2::Callback&)instance)
```

Comment: Or just `IWantAClass2Callback(instance)`, since the conversion is implicit (once the private inheritance problem is fixed). Explicit conversions should only be used if you want to do something weird, otherwise there's a danger of accidentally doing something weird.

Comment: In this case, you're right because the `Class2::Callback` is the interface - thus base class of anything passed. I just wanted to stick to the syntax given in the original question.